# Relative redirecting with or without the trailing slash

Tags: laravel, routes, uri, laravel-5.4, relative-path

Basically the problem I'm facing with my laravel server is very basic, but I somehow still struggle with that. It's all about relative redirecting. Let's say for example, I have following uri: `http://testsite.dev/configure`. It's returning a view and I have some link there. I'd like to make the link send me to `http://testsite.dev/configure/element-2`
But if no matter what href I put to the a tag, it always sends me to `http://testsite.dev/element-2`. I've tried:

```
 <a href="/element-2">
 <a href="element-2">
 <a href="../element-2">
 <a href="/../element-2">
```

Each time without success. So I finally came up with force putting a trailing slash at the end of the `/configure/`, but I doubt that's a good solution. Could you suggest the best way to do my relative redirecting? I basically want links to add up to the current url and not to rewrite it. Answer should be somewhere in the htaccess file... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
<a href="{{ url('configure') }}">Configure</a>
<a href="{{ url('configure/element-2') }}">Configure</a>
```

all `{{ function }}` does is echo the function.

Comment: Isn't there a way to tell the uri like "send me to that subdirectory, but of the current typed url", because I wouldn't like to put that `configure` everywhere.